# Next UI navbar menu won't close after selecting an item

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hooks, nextui

The navbar menu component won't close when the option from the menu was selected.

The menu successfully opens and closes within the menu icon.
I tried to to use onPress() but it doesn't seem to help a lot

```
"use client"
...
export default function Header() {
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = React.useState(false);
return(
...
<NavbarMenu>
        {menuItems.map((item, index) => (
          <NavbarMenuItem key={`${item}-${index}`}>
            <Link
              color="foreground"
              className="w-full"
              href={"#" + item.path}
              size="lg"
              onPress={() => {
                **console.log("closing")**; //Message appears
                **setIsMenuOpen(!isMenuOpen)**; //Menu won't close
              }}
            >
              {item.name}
            </Link>
          </NavbarMenuItem>
        ))}
</NavbarMenu>
)
```

UPD: when I remove `const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = React.useState(false);` the menu still opens/closes! It seems that there is a NavbarMenuToggle which has an onChange event which controls menu's behavior

https://nextui.org/docs/components/navbar#navbarmenutoggle-events

How to access this handler?

Comment: if you put setIsMenuOpen(false), does it close?

Comment: I am afraid no, it doesn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to control the menu directly with the "NavBar" component, which takes the following props:

- isMenuOpen
- onMenuOpenChange

These two props will allow you to control the toggle.

```
export default function Header() {
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = React.useReducer((current) => !current, false);

  return(
    // You need to control your toggle menu directly with the Navbar component.
    <Navbar isMenuOpen={isMenuOpen} onMenuOpenChange={setIsMenuOpen}>
      <NavbarMenu>
        {menuItems.map((item, index) => (
          <NavbarMenuItem key={`${item}-${index}`}>
            <Link
              color="foreground"
              className="w-full"
              href={"#" + item.path}
              size="lg"
              onPress={() => setIsMenuOpen()}
            >
              {item.name}
            </Link>
          </NavbarMenuItem>
        ))}
      </NavbarMenu>
    </Navbar>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more code?

I can give you example how it should look:

```
import React from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = React.useState(false);

  return (
     <div>
     <div
         onClick={() => {
         setIsMenuOpen(!isMenuOpen)
         console.log(isMenuOpen);}}
     >PRESS</div>
</div>
  )
}
```

Maybe you put useState hook at the wrong place?

Comment: There is an ouput in the console (true, false, true...) which means that the variable is changing but I'm afraid there's no effect

Answer (score 0):

I edited the file:
`<Navbar isMenuOpen={isMenuOpen}>`  navbar opens/closes when the variable is set to true/false

```
const togleMenu = () => {
setIsMenuOpen(!isMenuOpen);
console.log(isMenuOpen);

};


...

<NavbarMenuToggle
      aria-label={isMenuOpen ? "Close menu" : "Open menu"}
      className="sm:hidden"
      onClick={() => togleMenu()} // clicking on menu icon would change the value
    />

...

<NavbarMenuItem key={`${item}-${index}`}>
            <Link
              color="foreground"
              className="w-full"
              href={"#" + item.path}
              size="lg"
              onPress={() => togleMenu()} // change the value
            >
              {item.name}
            </Link>
```